# How do I use CSS attribute selector with the adjacent selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

For the following CSS how do I collectively use the attribute and adjacent selector?

```
.onoff-checkbox:checked + .onoff-label .onoff-inner {margin-left: 0;}
.onoff-checkbox:checked + .onoff-label .onoff-switch {right: 0px;}
```

I am using this to create CSS toggle style check-boxes, and would want to have more then one checkbox on the page? with the following HTML code (example):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="onoff" class="onoff-checkbox-1" id="myonoff" checked>
...
<input type="checkbox" name="onoff" class="onoff-checkbox-2" id="myonoff" checked>
```

I have tried the following -

```
input[class*="onoff-checkbox"]:checked + label[class*="onoff-label"] span[class*="onoff-inner"]
...
```

What is the correct syntax. Thanks for any help.

Here is the code to try out - https://jsfiddle.net/vedanta_/8z3sqatf/
Original code adapted from - https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/

Comment: Need to see more HTML. What you have shown does not sufficiently represent the selectors that you have - namely, the labels are missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the same `id` for more than one element. You could use **myonoff1** and **myonoff2**.

Then you can access it with CSS like this

```
#myonoff1
{
    ...
}

#myonoff2
{
    ...
}
```

And in jQuery, you can use this:

```
$('#myonoff1').show(); // or any other method.
```

Also, instead of using `div[class*="onoff"] {`, you can stick to the pattern with a class that the elements share. For example, in your HTML, you use `class="onoff-checkbox"` and in CSS you use `.onoff-checkbox { ... }`

Comment: I can use class to reference an element, it works as a wildcard when I generate elements using a code and a unique number - see example - https://jsfiddle.net/vedanta_/15702n8z/ - I now want to add the adjacent selector '+'

Comment: The uniqueness is what an `id` is for. It is possible with a class, but I strongly suggest that you stick to the correct pattern using id's and classes.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, I think you're confused as to what has to be unique.

(Someone correct me if I'm wrong), but I believe that the element's **id** should be the same as the element's **name**, and those are unique identifiers for the input element. The label's **for** attribute should reflect those exactly. Regardless, elements cannot share an **id**, nor can they share a **for** attribute.

The classes can absolutely be shared among input elements-- they don't have to be unique. So to go about this, I've fixed up your markup a little bit.

```css
div[class*="onoff"] {
    position: relative;
    width: 90px;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
input[class*="onoff-checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
label[class*="onoff-label"] {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
span[class*="onoff-inner"] {
    display: block;
    width: 200%;
    margin-left: -100%;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
span[class*="onoff-inner"]:before, span[class*="onoff-inner"]:after {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
span[class*="onoff-inner"]:before {
    content:"Yes";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #34A7C1;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
span[class*="onoff-inner"]:after {
    content:"No";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}
span[class*="onoff-switch"] {
    display: block;
    width: 18px;
    margin: 6px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 56px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
input[class*="onoff-checkbox"]:checked {
    margin-left: 0;
}
label[class*="onoff-label"] {
    margin-left: 0;
}
span[class*="onoff-inner"] {
    margin-left: 0;
}
input[class*="onoff-checkbox"]:checked {
    right: 0px;
}
label[class*="onoff-label"] {
    right: 0;
}
span[class*="onoff-inner"] {
    right: 0;
}
input.onoff-checkbox:checked + label.onoff-label span.onoff-switch {
    right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="onoff">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoff" class="onoff-checkbox" id="onoff" checked="true" />
    <label class="onoff-label" for="onoff"> 
        <span class="onoff-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoff-switch"></span>            
    </label>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="onoff2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoff2" class="onoff-checkbox" id="onoff2" checked="true" />
    <label class="onoff-label" for="onoff2">
        <span class="onoff-inner2"></span>
        <span class="onoff-switch"></span>                
    </label>
</div>
```

The main thing in the CSS to focus on is this line:

```
input.onoff-checkbox:checked + label.onoff-label span.onoff-switch {
    right: 5px;
}
```

This targets an element with the class of `.onoff-checkbox` and then applies styles based on the value of that.

You can see this in a **[working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8z3sqatf/5/)**.

Comment: An element doesn't have to have the same id and name attributes. The for attribute refers to the id only.

Comment: @BoltClock I thought the for attribute was for the name? But my point was that an id could be the same as the name, or typically should be.

Comment: No, the for attribute definitely refers to the id.

Comment: @BoltClock so what purpose does the name serve if there's already a unique identifier?

Comment: The name is used in form submission. I don't know the actual reason they made for refer to the id - if I were to guess, it seems related to the XML concept of an IDREF (unless XML borrowed *that* from HTML, in which case I'm flummoxed).